# Awk substr index 0

Tags: awk, string, indexing

I just discovered that `substr()` in awk accepts either 0 or 1 as the initial index in a string. I tested this in Gawk 5.1.0 and MacOS awk 20070501.

```
awk 'BEGIN {print substr("abcd", 0, 1)}'
```

outputs "a", as does

```
awk 'BEGIN {print substr("abcd", 1, 1)}'
```

and

```
awk 'BEGIN {print substr("abcd", 2, 1)}'
```

outputs "b" just to prove that nothing's obviously wrong.

I didn't see anything in the `man` pages or the Gawk `info` file other than mentions of 1-indexing.

For consistency with the documentation and with the fact that `index()` returns 1 for the first position and 0 for no match, it would be good policy to always use 1.

My question is why is this duality the case? Also, is it documented somewhere? Are there other awk implementations that do this?

Comment: In a quick check, BWK (original awk) and the updated [mawk](https://invisible-island.net/mawk/mawk.html) do this, but not older mawk.  Someone patient enough could bisect mawk to see if there's an explanation.

Comment: I've experienced quite a few differences between GNU awk and BSD awk, so much so that I try to avoid using it, or else rely explicitly on gawk in all cases.

Comment: BusyBox v1.33.1 awk also does this.

Comment: It's not a duality `awk accepts either 0 or 1`, gawk at least (and I suspect all modern awks) converts anything that's not a natural number to a natural number and use that as the index so any number less than 1 like 0 or -1, or any non-numeric string like `"foo bar"` get converted to 1, and any non integer numbers like 5.3 get truncated to whole numbers like 5, etc. If you run gawk with `--lint` it'll warn you if the index you provided is invalid before converting it.

Comment: It's unfortunate that negative indices are converted to 1 because it would be useful if they counted from the end of the string.

Comment: Yeah, I could see that. What I find interesting is that strings, generated arrays, and fields start at 1 in awk, but they all handle negative indices differently. `echo 'a b' | awk '{print substr($0,-1,1)}'` will output `a` as discussed above. But `echo 'a b' | awk '{print $-1}'` will output an error message like `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: attempt to access field -1` while `echo 'a b' | awk '{split($0,a); print a[-1]}'` will output a blank line. I understand why and each are reasonable but on the surface it's not particularly consistent across the 3 types of object :-).

Comment: more erroneous statements : `date | gawk -e '{OFS="|"; print $!(NF=NF); _=" 5*9Z "; print $_ }'
Fri|Jul|1|06:56:12|EDT|2022
EDT`   :::: a string `" 5*9Z "` with leading edge and trailing edge spaces  clearly isn't hex, (or arguably, even numeric at all), but gawk took in the `5` from its left side, as if one performed `$(+_)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [GNU awk online documentation: 'substr() function'](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-substr_0028_0029-function):

> If *start* is less than one, substr() treats it as if it was one. (POSIX
> doesn’t specify what to do in this case: BWK awk acts this way, and
> therefore gawk does too.) If *start* is greater than the number of
> characters in the string, substr() returns the null string. Similarly,
> if *length* is present but less than or equal to zero, the null string
> is returned.